# Using portable flash in a camera app

Tags: android, camera, flashlight

How can I support and give the orders to a portable flash like "Iblazr LED Flash" in my camera app.. and btw there's a couple of apps who done that on the market like "shot light"

Comment: Hi, you might want to refer to this other question, it seems like you only need to play a bit of audio to get the electric current running on the Audio jack https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560867/how-to-get-electric-power-from-head-phone-jack

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: There's an SDK for iblazr: https://github.com/ConcepterDev/iblazr-sdk-android