# Is it possible to control other physical devices via USB?

Tags: android, controls, device

I want to control a physical device which is connected to my android phone through USB. Here,physical device means any device (like camera,pc etc...) which can be connected to my android device via USB.I want to control this device from my phone. 
Is it possible?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible in some way. If you are able to control an RS232 to USB converter like the PL2303 (the normal ones that you get in the market) then you will be able to do many things. For this you will need a device that supports USB host, then you can check this [PL2303 test project](https://code.google.com/p/indiserver/downloads/detail?name=PL2303testV0.4.zip) which I already tested and can say that works very good. You can use it as the start point for controlling the USB port. This solution works for RS232 compatible devices which you can easily adapt with some electronics using a micro controller.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can control the devices but via OTG cable.

see [this](http://zungtran.hubpages.com/hub/Amazing-things-you-can-do-with-just-2-device-on-your-Android-device) link

Comment: Is it possible to control 'any device' which can be  connected to my phone via USB from my phone using this? I want a programmatic solution.

Comment: You mean you need to write a program for each device that can be controled?

Comment: M'am you have asked some serious question without the research. Its a research topic that leads you into the augmented reality and many more ways.
refer following links

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908530/external-usb-devices-to-android-phones

http://www.engadget.com/2011/04/10/sparkfun-intros-ioio-for-android-a-hack-free-breakout-box-to-ge/

Answer (score 0):

run adb_win from here http://smart-dog.appspot.com/download/ADB_WIN.zip
and connect to it with tightvnc viewer.
it worked for me

Answer (score -1):

```
Yes i have this question as well i tried to find the solution,Yes it is possible 
 do the following...
   1 - Android USB drivers must be installed on your desktop
   2 - USB Debugging must be enabled on your Android device
   3 - Your firewall should authorize adb.exe and BirdieSync.exe
   4 - Use the latest version of BirdieSync
   If u need more information visit this site it will help you...

   http://www.birdiesync.com/my-android-device-cannot-connect-over-usb
```

Comment: Is it possible to 'control any device' which can be connected to my phone via USB from my phone using this? I want a programmatic solution